# Smartcard exception Interenal transmit execution

Tags: android, smartcard, open-mobile-api

In my android application, I use a smartcard using OpenMobileAPI.

After creating a channel, when I transmit a command APDU, I often get an Exception like:

```
Exception plugin internal error:internalTransmit()
execution:java.lang.IllegalStateException:internal error.
```

What does this exception mean? What should I do?

Comment: You might have better luck on OpenMobileAPI forums/mailing lists, since this is very specific. Is this the whole error message? Are there any warnings?

Comment: @NikolayElenkov No this is the whole error message that i get.And also i get *Invalid Handle* Exception.I dont know the relation between these two. Once i get this i cannot send anymore command apdu further.

Comment: You are losing connection for some reason, or the code is trying to use the wrong handle due to a some sort of bug. Really, ask on their maling list, the actual developers are probably the only people that know what is going on.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Thanx. Can u give the link for *openmobileAPI* forum.

Comment: Well, since you are using their software, you should know :) I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You may find support on the [SEEK for Android](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) project page. I would advise you share more details, mostly the phone you are using and the smart card reader you have selected in the first place (UICC or micro SD ?). Maybe some code would help.